# my SignUp form is not submitting in django

Tags: django, django-forms

i used django-allauth and i found out that i need to add some more fields to the Sign Up form,now everything is working fine not until i tried to submit the form and i get redirected back to the signup page without submitting or saving the request nor giving me an error please help here is my forms.py and in there are the additional fields i want

### Forms.py

```
class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyCustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['First_name'] = forms.CharField(required=True)
        self.fields['Last_name'] = forms.CharField(required=True)
        self.fields['Phone_number'] = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
        self.fields['Servives'] = forms.BooleanField(required=True)
        self.fields['Payment_Mode'] = forms.CharField(required=True)
        self.fields['City'] = forms.CharField(required=True)
        self.fields['Servives'] = forms.CharField(required=True)
        


    def save(self, request):
        First_name = self.cleaned_data.pop('First name')
        Last_name = self.cleaned_data.pop('Last name')
        Phone_number = self.cleaned_data.pop('Phone number')
        Servives = self.cleaned_data.pop('Servives')
        Payment_Mode = self.cleaned_data.pop('Payment Mode')
        City = self.cleaned_data.pop('City')
        user = super(MyCustomSignupForm, self).save(request)
```

### templates.html

```
                   <form method="post">
                     {% csrf_token %}
                          <div class="form-row">
                       <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                   {{ form.First_name|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                
                                    {{ form.Last_name|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                          
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                  
                                     {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                 
                                    {{ form.Phone_number|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                           <div class="form-row">
                             <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                              {{ form.Payment_Mode|as_crispy_field }}
                                    </div>
                                    
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
                                    
                                     {{ form.City|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                              
                                 <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
                                   
                                     {{ form.Servives|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                                 </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-submit text-center">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: That's a very long sentence...

Comment: Please provide more information such as the form in your template and your view code

Comment: in `__init__()` why you declared `self.fields['Servives']` twice with 2 different field name ?

Comment: in django-allauth its just the form and the templates

Comment: @cizario i made the mistake while posting my question

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem here is the solution, i did not add form.password in my html so its directing me back to the form to fill in